# Get one div above the div of certain class PHP DOMDocument

Tags: php, domdocument

This is the first time i am using PHP DOMDocument and i don't know its methods.

I grab the html that has the following format

```
<div class=row abc>...</div>
<div class=row xyz>...</div>
<div class=row qrs>...</div>
...
...
<div class="row>This is what i want to grab</div>
<div class="row show-more-result">Show More</div>
```

What i am trying to achieve is that first i select the div with class `show-more-results` and then target the one level upper div thats where my data is present.

I have started exploring the PHP DOMDocument class but there is not any `getElementByClass` method i found

```
public function scrapping()
{
    // Create a DOMDocument Object to fetch the search results
    $dom = new \DOMDocument;
    @$dom->loadHTML($this->_response);
    $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;

    $xpath = new \DomXpath($dom);
    $show_more_div = $xpath->query('//*[@class="show-more-result"]')->item(0);
    $stuff = $show_more_div->textContent;

    echo($stuff);

}
```

I tried to target the show more div but it says `Trying to get property of non-object` as if the `$xpath-query()` returns nothing.

Please help me in targeting the desired div.

**Updated**

```
var_dump($xpath->query('//*[@class="show-more-result"]')->item(0));
// NULL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing a straight string equality:

```
$show_more_div = $xpath->query('//*[@class="show-more-result"]')->item(0);
                                       ^^^^^^^
```

But your target div's class is actually `row show-more-result`. You need to do a substring match instead:

```
//*[contains(@class, 'show-more-result')]
```

Comment: That worked thanks. Can you please tell me what method can i use to grab the one level upper div for this show more div ?

Comment: xpath has all kinds of "look around" options for this kind of stuff, sinc eit's all just a tree. you probably want "previous-sibling, `//*[...]/previous-sibling`